# Chart not rendering with pug/jade and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js, pug

I'm trying (about a week!!) to render a chart that works totally fine with hardcoded labels, but with my labels (data) from MySQL it shows nothing but a blank page.

However, if I console.log my labels, it shows me all the data sent from my DB which I want to put as labels to my chart.

In my **index.js**:

```
router.get('/api', function (req, res) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/projetos/quantos/ci')
        .then(dados =>{
            const d = dados.data;
            var labelsx = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
                labelsx.push(d[i].Nome);
            }
            console.log(labelsx);

            var datax = [];
            for(var j = 0; j < d.length; j++){
                datax.push(d[j].QuantosHa)
            }
            console.log(datax);
            res.render('chart',
                {title: "chart",
                 datai: JSON.stringify(datax),
                 labeli: labelsx
                })
        })
        .catch(erro => {e: erro});
});
```

My **chart.pug**:

```
extends layout

block content
    script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js")


    div
        each l in labeli
            ul=l

        div
            .chart-container
            canvas#chartPic
            script.
                var ctx = document.getElementById("chartPic").getContext('2d');
                ctx.canvas.parentNode.style.width = '50%';
                var idata = #{datai};
                var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: {
                        labels: [],
                        datasets: [{
                            data: idata,
                            backgroundColor: ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'pink', 'black'],
                            borderColor: ['green', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'pink'],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: "top 5 centros com mais projetos"
                        },
                        legend: {
                            position: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }
                });
```

If i put, for example ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"] in my chart's labels field it render with no problem and also that "each l in labeli" works just fine, but everytime I try to pass it to my chart, page goes blank like this:

[image: Result when I try to put my labels in my chart]
If i put it like its showing the pug code I get the chart:
[image]

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance for any suggestion you may have!

Answer (score 1):

Inside **index.js**, you should not convert `datax` to a `string` but simply pass the original `array`. Remove `JSON.stringify` from the code block below.

```
res.render('chart',
    { title: "chart",
      datai: JSON.stringify(datax),
      labeli: labelsx
    })
```

It should looks as follows.

```
res.render('chart',
    { title: "chart",
      datai: datax,
      labeli: labelsx
    })
```

**UPDATE**

In **chart.pug** you forgot to define the `labels`. Instead of an empty array, you should change the code as follows.

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: #{labeli}, // <- make this change
```

Comment: If I do that, my chart doesnt render at all... The problem isn't the data, but the labels

Comment: I've already tried that and still not works. Everytime I try to insert "labeli" anywhere in the script the chart goes blank. I really I don't get what's happening

Answer (score 0):

It might be to late to answer this question but I was also facing the same issue and couldn't find any answer. The following steps did the trick.

1. Remove JSON stringify before sending the response

```js
res.render('chart',
  {
    title: "chart",
    datai:  datax,
    labeli: labelsx
  }
)
```

2. And Data is returned in a single comma separated string. So I use the [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to create an array.

```js
{
  //...
  datasets: [{
    data: ('#{datai}').split(','),
    backgroundColor: ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'pink', 'black'],
    borderColor: ['green', 'blue', 'red', 'black', 'pink'],
                            borderWidth: 1
  }],
  //...
}
```